# How to create payment gateway module that will redirect to external page

Tags: payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

how can i create a payment gateway module that will redirect the customer to an external url when the customer places an order? I have tried using ultimate module creator but my module isn't appearing in the payment methods tab in the configurations menu.

Comment: What's your Magento Version?

Answer (score 3):

You can find skeleton to integrate custom payment gateway

Git Link for [Magento_Payment_Gateway_Skeleton](https://github.com/ergopalpatel/Magento_Payment_Gateway_Skeleton)

Compatible with all **magento 1.x version**

Answer (score 2):

You must create a public function in your payment model called: `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` and returns the (internal) URL where you should implement the code for the redirection. You can take a look at paypalStandard method to figure out exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps to create a custom payment gateway, [here are some options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/custom-payment-module-based-on-the-sample-gateway-code). Then for the redirect to an external url, use this function: _redirectUrl().

```
$this->_redirectUrl('https://www.yourwebsite.com');
```

To redirect when the customer places an order:

In your gateway Model:

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
return Mage::getUrl('payment_gateway/index/redirect');
}
```

In your gateway Index Controller:

```
public function redirectAction() 
{
$this->_redirectUrl('https://www.yourwebsite.com');
}
```