# Custom Payment Module Based on the Sample gateway code

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I am working to develop a payment gateway for Mpesa, a payment wallet we use in Kenya.

I have done one for Zencart which works perfectly. Unfortunately I have not worked with Magento much and need assistance for a starting point.

I just need to send a soap request and receive and interpret the response. I would love to get an idea which files based on the sample payment gateway module provided by Magento I will need to work on.

Comment: Is this for Magento 1 or 2?

Comment: this is for magento 2. i finally managed to implement. you can see the example at www.abigail.co.ke

Answer (score 0):

You can use below of 3 links which very useful to you to make your own custom extension for payment gateway in Magento 1.9.x

just go throw

1- [Create a Custom Payment Method Module in Magento (tutorial)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-module-in-magento-part-one--cms-23464)

or

2- [Magento payment extension](http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/)

or

3- [How to create Magento payment module](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)

hope this will sure help you.